# Callback of a object member function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function(){

    this.x = function(){alert('apple');}
    this.y = function(callback){
        if(typeof callback == 'undefined' || callback == null)
            alert('argh')
        else
            callback();
    }
}
var foo = function(){alert('blah')};
var x = new a();
x.y(this.x); // why is this one undefined
x.y(foo); // works as expected
```

​
here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/W7FyZ/2/

Why is it undefined when I pass in a object member function?  Is there a way to pass a object member function as a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just renamed your variable to clear the confusion.

```
var a = function(){
    this.x = function(){alert('apple');}
    this.y = function(callback){
        if(typeof callback == 'undefined' || callback == null)
            alert('argh')
        else
            callback();
    }
}
var foo = function(){alert('blah')};
```

Now, In the execution part:

```
var myA = new a();
```

Above line is assigning  function a() variable 'myA'. So,Functions `x()` and `y()` of `a()`,should be called as `myA.x()` and `myA.y()`.

```
x.y(myA.x); // it works 
x.y(this.myA.x) // This also works as this is a current window
x.y(foo); // works as expected
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do `x.y(this.x)`, `this` is a reference to the window, not an instance of `a`. I think what you may have intended was:

```
x.y(x.x);
```

Since `x` is an instance of `a`, this passes a reference to the `x` method of this instance of `a` to the `y` method of this instance of `a`.

When you do `x.y(foo)`, `foo` is a function declared in this scope, so you pass a reference to the `foo` function into the `y` method of `x`.

Comment: hmm, interesting, but when I try this inside a require dojo where x is an object of a dojo module, chrome says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'func' of undefined

Comment: @Derek - You'll have to clarify your question further, probably with a bit more code. I'm not entirely sure what you mean.